# react api call with authentication

Tags: reactjs

In Api response you will be able to get user details including auth token. you will use this token for calling a secure API to get the list of users.
https://reqres.in/api/unknown

headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ',
‘Content-type’:’application/json’
}
Print the list of users in console

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How can i get the list of name from object nested array nested object through API call.  For ex. {"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"name":"cerulean","year":2000,"color":"#98B2D1","pantone_value":"15-4020"},{"id":2,"name":"fuchsia rose","year":2001,"color":"#C74375","pantone_value":"17-2031"},{"id":3,"name":"true red","year":2002,"color":"#BF1932","pantone_value":"19-1664"},{"id":4,"name":"aqua sky","year":2003,"color":"#7BC4C4","pantone_value":"14-4811"}],"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free"}}